# Integrate in Zenoss remote data

Tags: monitoring, snmp, zenoss

I need to monitor several Linux servers placed in a different location from my farm.

I have VPN connection to this remote location.

Internally I use Zenoss 4 to monitor the systems, I would like to use Zenoss to monitor remote systems too. For contract policy, I cannot use VPN connection for Zenoss data (e.g. SNMP or SSH).

What I created is a bunch of scripts that fetch desired data from remote systems to an internal server. The format of the returned data is one CVS per every location, containing data from all appliances placed in that location.

For example:

```
$ cat LOCATION_1/current/current.csv
APPLIANCE1,out_of_memory,no,=,no,3,-
APPLIANCE1,postgre_idle,no,=,no,3,-
APPLIANCE2,out_of_memory,no,=,no,3,-
APPLIANCE2,postgre_idle,no,=,no,3,-
```

The format of CVS is this one:

> HOSTNAME,CHECK_NAME,RESULT_VALUE,COMPARE,DESIRED_VALUE,INFO

How can i integrate those data in Zenoss, as the machines were placed in the internal farm?
If it is necessary, I could eventually change the format of fetched data.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is for your internal server that communicates with remote systems (let's call it `INTERNAL1`) to re-issue the events as SNMP traps (or write them to the `rsyslog` file) and then process them in Zenoss.

For example, the message can start with the name of the server: `"[APPLIANCE1] Out of Memory"`. In the "Event Class transform" section of your Zenoss web interface (http://my_zenoss_install.local:8080/zport/dmd/Events/editEventClassTransform), you can transform attributes of incoming messages (using Python). I frequently use this to lower the severity of an event. E.g.,

```
if evt.component == 'abrt' and evt.message.find('Saved core dump of pid') != -1:
    evt.severity = 2     # was originally 3, I think
```

For your needs, you can set the `evt.device` to `APPLIANCE1` if the message comes from `INTERNAL1`, and contains `[APPLIANCE1]` tag as the message prefix, or anything else you want to use to uniquely identify messages/traps from remote systems.

I don't claim this to be the best way of achieving your goal. My knowledge of Zenoss is strictly limited to what I currently need to use it for.

P.S. [here](http://community.zenoss.org/docs/DOC-2554) is a rather old document from Zenoss about using event transforms. Unfortunately documentation in Zenoss is sparse and scattered (as you may have already learned), so searching old posts and/or asking questions on the Zenoss forum may be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can deploy one collector in remote location, and you add that host into collector pool , you can monitor remote linux servers also